# Transform differential equation into a equation with separate variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As an exercise in a textbook, I am supposed to transform the differential equation (where $x$ is a function of $t$, $f$ is some function and $a$,$b$ and $c$ are constants)

$$ \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = f(at+bx+c) $$

into an equation with separate variables. This is Chapter 1 of the book, so I am not familiar with any advanced techniques. At any rate, I have no idea how to approach this problem. I tried differentiating the equation $f(at+bx+c) = g(x)h(t)$ with respect to $t$ but that only made the problem more complicated.

I'm not asking for a solution, since ideally I'd like so solve the problem myself...are there any possible hints that would put me on the right track with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=a t+b x+c$.  Then

$$\frac{du}{dt} = a+b \frac{d x}{dt} $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck. I see that I can solve for $dx/dt$ to get $f(u) = [\frac{du}{dt} - a]/b$ but that doesn't help either...at least I don't think so.

Comment: That's essentially it as far as I understand.  You now have a diff eq in which the dependent and independent variables are separate.  The solution is now just a matter of integrating $$\frac{du}{a+b f(u)} = dt$$

Comment: Oh, I see--so I could write the equation as $\frac{du}{dt} = a+b f(u)$ and then separate variables to $\frac{du}{a+bf(u)} = dt$? (Wow, sniped.)

Comment: Yes, just what I was writing!

Comment: But wait, sorry if this is a dumb question but what does that have to do with separating $x$ and $t$? Don't I already know what $u$ is since I set it to be $at+bx+c$?

Comment: I can't vouch for how the problem was worded, but I think "separating" means making the equation separable rather than just "separating" $x$ and $t$.  Which is what we did.

Comment: OK I JUST UNDERSTOOD IT! Thank you for your help.